# Connecting a webserver from host to guest vmware os?

Tags: windows-7, vmware, opensuse

I've a webserver in my vmware guest os suse 12.2 running but how can I connect it from my host os? My virtual machine is configured with NAT option in vmware network manager but I can't ping my vm from my host os? I've tried this tutorial to no avail: http://www.nwlab.net/tutorials/VMware/. I add port forwarding to my vm from port 80 to port 80. It's using vmnet8 and my adapter has a different ip then my guest? Is this normal behaviour? This is the same question but I can't get it work: [How can I connect to a web server running in a VM when the VM is in NAT mode?](https://superuser.com/questions/245156/how-can-i-connect-to-a-web-server-running-in-a-vm-when-the-vm-is-in-nat-mode)?

Edit: Hmm, it works. I've installed vmware-tools and after a reboot of the host it works? I've also enabled port-forwarding. I typed ifconfig in guest os and I used this ip in host os to load the webserver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the virtual machine is running on VMNET8, then you will need to ensure that one of the virtual network adaptors in your host machine is running on VMNET8, as at present they are likely on differing networks.

Comment: But in my guest os I've internet access over my host os?

Comment: It will most likely be connecting out using a NAT, which whilst letting you out may not let you back in the same way.

Comment: My adapter is running on vmnet8 that's where I get the info from. I don't understand why my adapter has a different ip then my guest os?

Comment: They run on a virtual network that allows the VM to communicate with the host. The host adapter will have a different address than the guest, that's by design otherwise their addresses would clash.

Comment: Hmm, it works. I've installed vmware-tools and after a reboot of the host it works? I've also enabled port-forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set up passthrough networking on the VM network interface so that it can connect to your actual network.

Comment: I don't understand?

Answer (score -1):

NAT prevents inbound access from outside. That's what it's meant to do. Configure your VM network adapter as bridged for any server running in a VM.